# Solution for touch-friendly NESTED nav menus?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navigation

A common problem I run into when building responsive websites is how to make a multi-level nav menu (3 or more levels) that works well for touch devices. I've seen a lot of plugins and techniques, but most of them fall flat because they don't allow a 2nd-level page to act as both a link to a page AND a parent of children in a sub-sub-menu. Some techniques address this by having an arrow icon that exposes the children menu items while clicking on the parent page name goes to the actual page... but on mobile devices these icons are usually very small targets and hence hard to use. Are there any other solutions to this problem (either jquery or javascript plugins, or straight-up CSS/JS code)?

Comment: touch once, add class to the parent and show sub menu, touch again check for the class and do whatever is needed, same thing goes for the rest of the sub levels. The class is the gatekeeper to determine if the user opened the sub nav or not. See http://www.lexus.ca main nav on mobile devices

Comment: @Huangism - the lexus.ca menu links exhibit the problem I mention: the 2nd-level pages ("Shopping Tools", "Parts & Service", etc.) *only* expand their children -- there is no way to click on those 2nd-level pages themselves. It looks like on that particular site, there aren't actually pages for those, so it works for them. But I'm specifically referring to sites where those menu items *do* correspond to actual pages.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but you can click on the second level navs, so if you go Shopping Tools > Quick Estimator - by touching the item once on mobile, it shows the dropdown and touching it again it will go to the page. So by tapping Quick Estimator 2 times you will go to the page. Is this what you are trying to do or am I missing the point?

Comment: When I visit the site on my iphone, tapping on "Shopping Tools" only expands or collapses its children... it never takes me to an actual page (regardless of how many times I tap on it). And tapping on "Quick Estimator" always takes me to a page... it never expands children (regardless of how many times I tap on it). My question is how to have 1 menu item serve both purposes at the same time.

Comment: It doesn't go on the iphone because you need to be able to collapse the menu. What do you mean 1 menu that serves both purpose, how are you expecting to know when you should expand/collapse and when you should go to the link? You can make it so that it will expand on first click then go to a link on second click, however in this case, you will not be able to collapse the menu. On tablet it will do this first click show and second click go to page. But note that the menu on tablet does not need to collapse.

Comment: If you want both functionality then you need to add an extra item to clearly indicate to collapse the menu or an extra item to clearly indicate 'go to link', the collapse/expand icon is more friendly. But you cannot have 1 item that does both collapse and go to link because you don't know what the user want at that point in time. If you think the extra item is too small then make it bigger and more noticable

Comment: THank you Huangism for your comments -- this is the heart of my question (which could be stated as "are there any creative design solutions to the problem of having a nav menu item serve both purposes of being a link and expanding its children, without resorting to a separate icon"). Your answer appears to be "no, you have to have 2 separate targets, and if the icon is too small, just make it bigger". If you write this as an actual answer I will upvote it (and eventually mark it as "accepted" if nobody else comes along with another idea). Thanks again, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 'starting point' of sorts that I use for responsive web projects like this. I'm not sure if it's exactly what you need, but it allows for multi-level dropdown menus in desktop view. In mobile view, jQuery automatically creates an off-canvas menu.

Code:
https://github.com/kthornbloom/Responsive_Template

Demo:
http://rwd.kthornbloom.com/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out any of the documentation surrounding touch-start events? I feel like you're going to get the best ux from this method. In your position, I'd be using tap to toggle classes onto your menu that would set the display to block (for example). Once your menu is open, you could then bind another touch event to the sub-level objects.

Answer (score 1):

After our discussion in comments, it seems there isn't a straight forward way to get what you want due to the fact that we don't know what the user want after the submenu has been opened. There is no way for us to tell if they want to go to a link by clicking on the item again or collapse the submenu.

From this point, you have 2 options

1. Create a collapse once the menu is open and the user will know to use that to collapse the menu. If you think the size on most sites are small then make it bigger, however I don't think this will be an issue because it is so common.
2. Create a close button or something close to that for the entire menu. So when you click an item, it will expand, and if you click the same item again, it will go to the link. However there is collapsing the submenu until you click on the overall close button for the entire menu. This is only for tablets/phones as on desktop this should be a hover behaviour. This is similar to how the menu behaves on a tablet for http://www.lexus.ca. We actually have the menu closing if you click on the top most item again, you can see this behaviour on the phone or tablet. This is another option for you if the top level navs does not lead to pages.

Answer (score 0):

Found a great write-up for a solution: http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly